# Create multidimensional array from database query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am new to PHP Codeigniter. I have a database inner join query in that I am fetching category id, category name, subcategory id and subcategory name as shown below.

e.g. 
[image]

I am figuring out the way to create multidimensional array with category id, name and subcategories details as an in it.

e.g.

```
Array[0]=>Array ( [category_id] => 1 [category_name] => Computer [sub] => 
          Array ([0]=> [subcategory_id] => 1 [subcategory_name] => C Programming ) 
                 [1]=> [subcategory_id] => 2 [subcategory_name] => Website Development) 
                 [2]=> [subcategory_id] => 4 [subcategory_name] => Java)) 

Array[1]=>Array ( [category_id] => 2 [category_name] => Robotics [sub] => 
          Array ( [subcategory_id] => 3 [subcategory_name] => Robo Wars))
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the following is your result array from db

```
$queryResult = array(
  array('category_id'=>1,'category_name'=>'Computer','subcategory_id'=>1,'subcategory_name'=>'C Programming','category_id'=>'1'),
  array('category_id'=>1,'category_name'=>'Computer','subcategory_id'=>2,'subcategory_name'=>'Website Development','category_id'=>'1'),
  array('category_id'=>1,'category_name'=>'Computer','subcategory_id'=>4,'subcategory_name'=>'Java','category_id'=>'1'),
  array('category_id'=>2,'category_name'=>'Robotics','subcategory_id'=>3,'subcategory_name'=>'Robo Wars','category_id'=>'2'),
);
```

Then you could try

```
$result = array();
foreach($queryResult as $arr){
  $result[$arr['category_id']]['category_id']= $arr['category_id'];
  $result[$arr['category_id']]['category_name'] = $arr['category_name'];
  $result[$arr['category_id']]['sub'][]= array('subcategory_id'=>$arr['subcategory_id'],'subcategory_name'=>$arr['subcategory_name']);
}
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying to solve this from last two days. You saved me.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post your query, but I'll assume it looks something like this;

```
$sql = 'SELECT whatever FROM my_table WHERE category = ?';

$data = array(
    $category
);

$query = $this->db
    ->query( $sql, $data )
    ->result_array();
```

Adding the `->result_array()` function to your query will return an associative array instead of an object.